# My Wordpress did not executed well if I access from another computer [in localhost]

Tags: wordpress, localhost, share

I was installed wordpress in my computer and I use XAMPP. I already set XAMPP to make it share and can access from another computer, and it works. I can access my web from another computer, but I can't access my wordpress from another computer. It just showing text from the posts and not showing the form. It's like the script did not executed well.

advice please :(

Comment: This is a Wordpress question. Ask on [wordpress.se]

Comment: I've been looking for it, but I did not find it. May be you have some advices for me?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I did had the same problem. And i was able to fix it just by changing the localhost IP of the computer that wants to access the other computer where the test site is hosted. Go to
 **C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\**

on the computer that wants to access the other, then look for the host file and add this line:
**xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx localhost**

at the very bottom. Make sure you change the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx into the IP of the computer where your test site is hosted.